# mpicxx: Command not found

Tags: linux, environment-variables, mpi, opensuse

I am very new to linux. I am trying to build lammps open source software with user defined modules that require to build mpi executable on opensuse leap 15.1.
lammps - https://lammps.sandia.gov/doc/Build_make.html

It showed an error: mpicxx xommand not found.
after searching i did "sudo zypper in gcc-c++" and tried again.
same error
so I did "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib64/mpi/gcc/openmpi/bin"
and make mpi was successful and it built lmp_mpi executable but when i tried to run with lmp_mpi it showed following error:
error while loading shared libraries: libmpi_cxx.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file

so I wrote "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib64/mpi/gcc/openmpi/bin" in my bashrc file and ran again make mpi and tried again same error is shown.

I tried by installing mpich2 with yast same error is shown.

Then I tried by installing openmpi as shown here http://edu.itp.phys.ethz.ch/hs12/programming_techniques/openmpi.pdf
When I tried to build mpi again same error "mpicxx: Command not found error" and also when I open terminal following lines are written already.
bash: /home/surya/.bashrc: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
bash: /home/surya/.bashrc: line 1:`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$HOME/opt/openmpi/lib >'

Someone please help me I have been trying this for long time.

Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: you should have `/usr/lib64/mpi/gcc/openmpi/lib/libmpi_cxx.so.1`. in that case, no need to reinstall mpi, just rebuild it with the one in `/usr/lib64/mpi/gcc/openmpi/bin` and set both `$PATH` and `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` accordingly (and without extra garbage at the end)

Answer (score -1):

Try

"make serial" instead of "make mpi"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).